# Abort Trap: 6 error in the new Swift 3.1/Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I have a finished project with about 30vcs, Firebase, Googlemaps integration, etc - ie a really big complicated project, it is a geolocation based game that I've finally finished after several months of work.

Worked and compiled just fine, until I tried to compile it in the new Swift 3.1/ Xcode 8.3.

After changing the recommended syntax on a few lines to clear the new XCODE 8.3 errors, compiling fails with "Abort Trap: 6" error.

This is the last few lines of the debugger (prior to that theres about 100 lines of incomprehensible file names/numbers etc).

> 0  swift                    0x00000001089f1eb7
>   PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 39 1  swift
>   0x00000001089f1366 SignalHandler(int) + 646 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffc602eb3a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000100000001 _sigtramp + 972887265 4 
>   libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fffc5eb3420 abort + 129 5  swift
>   0x0000000106454644
>   swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt,
>   llvm::Optional) + 38404 6  swift
>   0x00000001064564fa
>   swift::ModuleFile::getType(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt)
>   + 2106 7  swift                    0x000000010644f373 swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt,
>   llvm::Optional) + 17203 8  swift
>   0x0000000106459f24
>   swift::ModuleFile::maybeReadPattern(swift::DeclContext*) + 740 9 
>   swift                    0x000000010644f605
>   swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt,
>   llvm::Optional) + 17861 10 swift
>   0x00000001064607c8 swift::ModuleFile::loadAllMembers(swift::Decl*,
>   unsigned long long) + 600 11 swift
>   0x0000000106840f0d swift::NominalTypeDecl::getMembers() const + 125 12
>   swift                    0x0000000106828c75 (anonymous
>   namespace)::Traversal::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) +
>   869 13 swift                    0x0000000106826645 (anonymous
>   namespace)::Traversal::doIt(swift::Decl*) + 277 14 swift
>   0x000000010619a75f
>   swift::SILPassManager::SILPassManager(swift::SILModule*,
>   llvm::StringRef) + 1471 15 swift                    0x00000001061a135f
>   swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 159 16 swift
>   0x0000000105811282 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef,
>   char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 42866 17 swift
>   0x00000001057c088c main + 9052 18 libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fffc5e1f235 start + 1 Stack dump:

(here is about 150 lines of incomprehensible debugging numbers/files/alphanumericals - followed by this in the end):

> 1. While loading members for 'homePage' in module 'googleMapsPractice'
>
>    2. While deserializing PatternBindingDecl #295in 'googleMapsPractice'
>    3. While deserializing 'gameDBRef' (VarDecl #296)in 'googleMapsPractice'
>    4. While deserializing decl #1009 (XREF)in 'googleMapsPractice'
>    5. Cross-reference to module 'FirebaseDatabase'    ... FIRDatabaseReference

I am really stuck as I don't know where to look to debug this.

'homePage.swift' is the set-up page VC of the game, and is the only VC referenced in the debugger, is there any common solutions to Abort Trap 6 errors that I could try weed out on this VC? It is probably 2000 lines of code and i'm not even sure the problem lies in that VC as the debugger is so vague.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In C, "Abort trap:6" refers to writing beyond the memory allowed, usually when writing to an array that isn't large enough.

Comment: thanks for the comment - all arrays I use were properly compiling up till xcode 8.2 - any way to check which specific array could cause this? I have several arrays, adding to them with .append with no issues at all in the code. Also - any idea if the above debugger message means the problems lie in "homepage.swift", or it could still be anywhere?

Comment: I assume you've tried the usual suspects such as restarting Xcode, cleaning the project, deleting derived data etc. correct? If not, you might want to try those first and if you still have the issue, a full screenshot of the compiler error might help somebody help you. If you can share the project with me, I'd be happy to take a look as well but I have a feeling that you might not be too keen on that :)

Comment: Thanks Fahim - yep tried everything u mentioned, all to no avail. I will try post a snapshot later today - on mobile now - hehe yes unfortunately cant share project with anyone :)

Comment: I added more info on the question above - this is pretty much all the relevant debugger info i am getting. I also updated cocoapods to the latest version, still same error, it cant compile

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I had a `private enum` in both the main `class`, and an `extension` of that class. Both of these were in the same file. Tricky one!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it appears that it was due to a local project scheme missing with a build phase in my application attempting to link to the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem. I finally figured out that it was caused by overriding 'var description' on any class that inherits from NSObject. I note that in Swift 3.1 there is a 'class func description()' on NSObject that I don't necessarily recall being in Swift 3.0 (although I could easily be mistaken in this assumption; I've never had any to look for or use it). See also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75700

Answer (score 1):

I faced the error because my class had a diffrent name than the filename. Corrected filename and everything worked fine then

Answer (score 1):

In my case was because I put a ! symbol in a init method of a object. Like this:

```
init(obj1: Object1, obj2: Object2!) {

}
```

Remove the ! of function parameter and no more error.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Swift classes that had properties with type `RCTRootView` from React. I fixed it by making the property private, turning something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  var rctView: RCTRootView()
}
```

Into something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  private var rctView: RCTRootView()
}
```

It seems that the error is in trying to deserialize classes from other modules/frameworks too early in compilation (in your case `FirebaseDatabase` and in my case `React`). Making this property private makes it so that the compiler doesn't need to do this till later in compilation. If I had to guess, it looks like we're sweeping some dependency/build order problems under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by switching to a different device in the simulator - it then compiled and ran fine.

Then, when I went back to the previous device it also worked fine.

I've no explanation!